# Unable to access wp-admin - Redirecting to upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to access

> localhost/mysite/wp-admin

and I am getting this message:

```
Your WordPress database is already up-to-date!
```

And it gives me an option to "Continue".

Does anybody know why I am not able to access wp-admin?

Answer (score 2):

The usual cause of this problem is related to cache.

Try to rename or delete the file `wp-content/object-cache.php` within your WordPress installation.

Comment: Did it. No use. It is still redirecting me to the upgrade page.

Comment: Are you sure your cache (browser and wordpress) is clean? Try accessing from a different browser.

Comment: Tried accessing from different browsers. Cleared the cache. No use!

Answer (score 0):

most probably some issue with WordPress installation as it is.

Try to access via wp-login.php instead

or you can even remove wp-config.php and re-install wordpress.